# Trying to get a list of unique forum posts, not working

Tags: mysql, sql

Quick overview, I am trying to get the last 5 forum posts from my forum table(s) to display to the user in the RHS column.

What I also want is that this list should only show unique forum post titles (sometimes users post the same post in multiple forums, I don't want my RHS box to have potentially the same 5 "titles" displayed, even though they are in different forum categories).

But this sql isn't quiet working... it's completely skipping any forum posts that have the same title multiple times, I still want multiply title entries, but only one.

```
SELECT 
    f.id,
    f.title,  
    fm.url_path
FROM forum_posts AS f
INNER JOIN forum_master AS fm 
    ON f.forum_id = fm.id 
WHERE deleted = 0
    AND blacklisted = 0
GROUP BY f.title
ORDER BY f.id DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

For example, consider this table

```
id  title
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
5   e
6   f
7   f
```

I want to return id's 7,5,4,3,2. I still want an instance of the title f, but only one. My code seems to be return 1-5 (completely skipping both id 6-7 because they have the same title).

Any thoughts????

Comment: I just tried this in a SQL fiddle and it seems like it's behaving as you describe it. Anything else you could add to help it break? Or am O misunderstanding something?  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce692/1

Comment: Thanks Lathejockey81... yes, your fiddle does seem to be running correctly. Hmmm, must have gremlins in my code, off to investigate and will reply back. Thanks for that!

Comment: This is really strange... after doing testing and var_dumps of the returning db result is definitely is skipping rows with the same title. Not sure if it makes a difference, but I'm on XAMPP (restarted the server, still same problem), running MySQL version 5.6.12. If I take out the GROUP BY I'm getting a result with 3 of the same titles, put it back in and I get none of those 3. Arghhh.

Comment: Okay, dumped my testing DB tables and an exact copy of my sql statement into the fiddle (running MySQL version 5.5.32) and it's returning correctly. Looks like my version of MySQL (5.6.12) is the culprit. Exact same tables/data and sql code returning different results. Do you think it could be anything else? I'm not sure if/how I can change the mysql version on xampp (easily) to test this theory and the fiddle doesn't have my version to mysql either.

Comment: The fiddle with my tables/data, exactly the same on my XAMPP application, returning different results. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/758b3e/3

Comment: The fiddle is just a simulation of what *should* happen, so there could be something that just isn't jiving betweeen MySql and SQLFiddle. I don't have a real MySQL server to test against at the moment, but you may have to resort to a nested query or something fun like that.

Comment: Okay thanks for that, I'll get cracking on coding a new sql statement. Grrr, should be simple, but wasted hours on this today. Thanks again for your support!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the nested query I have here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/758b3e/11

```
SELECT
  f.title,
  f.id,
  fm.url_path
FROM forum_posts AS f
INNER JOIN forum_master AS fm 
ON f.forum_id = fm.id 
WHERE deleted = 0
AND blacklisted = 0
AND (SELECT id
     FROM forum_posts
     WHERE title = f.title
     ORDER BY id DESC
     LIMIT 1) = f.id
ORDER BY f.id DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Instead of using a group by (which I believe would fail in Oracle under these circumstances - can't group with multiple IDs) I filtered id to a single possibility in the WHERE clause, which removes the duplicates and goes with the highest ID. The group by query was grabbing the lowest ID, so even if it was working it wouldn't be exactly what you're looking for as a solution.

Comment: That is GREAT. Almost working perfect... if the first "multiple title" entry was deleted or blacklisted no "multiple title" results were returned. Simply added the deleted/blacklists where clauses also in the sub-select and it's all perfect!!! Thank you very very much!!!